# Как вставить картинку и текст в QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qtabwidget

Есть два окна:

- в первом несколько табов и кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается вторая форма,
- в которой две кнопки, при нажатии на первую -   открывается выбор картинки (`QFileDialog`), при нажатии на вторую - `QInputDialog`, который просит ввести текст.

Как выбранную картинку и текст вставить в выбранный таб первого окошка?

Во втором окне можно указать размер и положение( **`x`** и **`y`**) картинки и текста.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class FirstForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('form1.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.secondform = SecondForm()
        self.secondform.btn2_2.clicked.connect(self.addimage)

    def addimage(self):
        self.fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.secondform, 'Выбрать картинку', '')[0]


    def open(self):
        self.secondform.show()


class SecondForm(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            uic.loadUi('form2.ui', self)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstForm()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

uic главного окна:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>541</width>
      <height>471</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 2</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Открыть второе окно</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

uic второго:

```
<widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>текст</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn2_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>картинка</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>190</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>61</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Положение</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>61</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Размеры</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте ваш код и хорошо расскажите куда вы хотите вставить выбранное изображение.

Comment: S. Nick, переделал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bставить картинку и текст в `QTabWidget` можно примерно так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *
    

class FirstForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('q1475435_form1.ui', self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)
       
        self.labelImage = QLabel(self.tab) 
        self.textInput = QLabel(self)
        
        self.secondform = SecondForm()
        self.secondform.signalOk.connect(self._insert)

    def _insert(self):
        pixmap = self.secondform.labelImage.pixmap()
        self.labelImage.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.textInput.setText(self.secondform.textInput.text())
        
        try:
            x1 = int(self.secondform.lineEdit_2.text()) 
            y1 = int(self.secondform.lineEdit_4.text())
            x2 = int(self.secondform.lineEdit.text()) 
            y2 = int(self.secondform.lineEdit_3.text())            
        except:
            x1 = 20 
            y1 = 20   
            x2 = 70 
            y2 = 180            
        
        self.labelImage.move(x1, y1)       
        self.labelImage.adjustSize()
        
        self.textInput.move(x2, y2) 
        self.textInput.adjustSize()

    def open(self):
        self.secondform.show()
                                                      

class SecondForm(QWidget):
    signalOk = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
            
        uic.loadUi('q1475435_form2.ui', self)

        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.getTextInputDialog) 
        self.btn2_2.clicked.connect(self.addimage)
        
        self.textInput = QLabel(self)
        self.textInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 61, 21))    

        self.labelImage = QLabel(self)
        self.labelImage.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 170, 200, 125))
        
        self.btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Вставить \nв первое \nокошко', self)
        self.btnOk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 230, 60, 60))
        self.btnOk.clicked.connect(self.signalOk.emit)

    def addimage(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Выбрать картинку', 
            '',
            'PNG Files (*.png);;JPG Files (*.jpg)',
        )
        
        if fname:
            self.labelImage.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(fname).scaled(200, 125))
            
    def getTextInputDialog(self):
        text, okPressed = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(
            None, 
            "Get text",
            "Введите текст:", 
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal, 
            "")   
        if okPressed and text:
            self.textInput.setText(text) 
            self.textInput.adjustSize()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstForm()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1475435_form1.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>541</width>
      <height>471</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 2</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>480</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Открыть второе окно</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**q1475435_form2.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>Form</class>
<widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>текст</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn2_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>101</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>картинка</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>190</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>61</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Положение</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>61</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Размеры</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>31</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]